# What models for backing out Equity IVOL

Tags: volatility, derivatives

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should I calculate the implied volatility of an American option in a real-time production environment?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/1489/how-should-i-calculate-the-implied-volatility-of-an-american-option-in-a-real-ti)

I am starting a project and would be grateful for some practical advice. My focus is on the informational content of equity derivatives,  (index, ETF & stocks). A central metric here is obviously IVOL. My question is what are the “industry” standard models for backing out IVOL from equity option prices? By “industry” I mean widely used by market practitioners. And which models have the best robustness & ease of implementation / accuracy trade off? Are there any pitfalls I should avoid?

To date my reading is taking me towards CRR tree solutions. I am aware of stochastic vol models and have looked at variations on the Model Free IVOL theme. But what would be most appropriate in today’s market?

Comment: Hi Tom, welcome to quant.SE. Please see the previous question linked above.  If you still have any other questions, update your question.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer - that is exactly what I am seeking. Regards.